# How to migrate my shell scripts to Azure

Tags: linux, shell, python, azure

I have a shell script, orchestrating and running some linux commands, python, ffmpeg, and Azure services (via CLI), periodically on my local machine. And my whole solution is based on those tools and languages.

I want to migrate the whole solution to be hosted on Azure instead of my computer. What solution would you recommend? I can think of two solutions but hope there would be an easier or a lift and shift way

1. rewrite everything in python and deploy in Azure Functions.
2. try to replicate all tools and scripts in my VMs on Azure, and do the same thing as the local machine

Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: if the yrun on your local system and I assume that is running on a Linux distro, deploy the same distro on a Azure VM. Or build a container and deploy them using Azure Container Instance.

Answer (score 0):

you can activate your cloud shell and host all your scripts in the shell[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the scripts do and how those scripts need be run. I would probably choose to deploy a single VM on Azure.
Also, Azure Functions would do for event triggered executions (new file event, time event, etc), assuming that libraries\executables that the scripts need are usable in Azure.

Note: The Azure Cloud shell will shut down after 20 minutes of inactivity so it's probably not suitable unless you perform those tasks manually.